# Localizar valor dentro de um array

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
    array (size=80)
    0 => 
    array (size=2) 
        ‘cod_produto' => int 107 
        'valor' => float 20 
    1 =>        
    array (size=2) 
        ‘cod_produto' => int 109 
        'valor' => float 375.8 
    2 => 
    array (size=2) 
        ‘cod_produto' => int 112 
        'valor' => float 20
```

Estou montando ele assim:

```
Loop {

    // Monta array
    $valores[] = array(
        "cod_produto" => (int) $resultado_precos-> cod_produto,
        "valor" => (float) $resultado_precos->valor
    );
}
```

O array está em uma variável `$valores`, preciso recuar o valor do produto em um relatório, porém tenho apenas o `cod_produto`.

Preciso buscar no array o valor do produto e caso o valor não exista tenho que exibir o valor como zero.

Resumindo, eu tenho o código do produto e preciso localizar o preço dele nesse array.

Comment: Acredito que a função in_array do PHP te sirva.
Dá uma olhada na documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php

Comment: Como assim "recuar o valor do produto"? Você possui o código do produto e deseja buscar nesse *array* qual é o valor associado?

Comment: Melhor ainda, a função array_search.
Doc: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:
$cod = array_search($busca, $valor);

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é isso mesmo, eu tenho o código do produto e preciso localizar o preço dele nesse array, desculpa não ter sido claro com minha pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
$valores = array (

    0 => 
    array(
        'cod_produto' => 107,
        'valor' => 20 
    ),

    1 =>     
    array (
        'cod_produto' => 109 ,
        'valor' => 375.8 
    ),

    2 => 
    array(
        'cod_produto' => 112 ,
        'valor' => 20
    )

);

$codProcura = 112;
$valor = 0;

for($x = 0; $x < count($valores); $x++){    
    $search = $valores[$x];
    if($search['cod_produto'] == $codProcura){
        $valor = $search['valor'];
        break;
    }
}

echo $valor;
```

**[Veja no ideone](https://ideone.com/RKvUk4)**

Existe uma outra forma usando o **[array_search](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php)**, como foi citado pelo @VitorAndre, junto com o **[array_colum](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php)**.

Assim:

```
$valor = 0;
$local = array_search(112, array_column($valores, 'cod_produto'));
$valor = $valores[$local]['valor'];
echo $valor;
```

Comment: Em questão de performance tem alguma diferença entes elas?

Comment: @HugoBorges eu tinha PENSADO que o `for` era mais rápido. Mas fiz uns testes e não muda muito não..

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar também uma função com `foreach`:

```
$valores = array(
   array('cod_produto' => 101,'valor' => 200),
   array('cod_produto' => 102,'valor' => 300),
   array('cod_produto' => 103,'valor' => 400)
);

$buscar = 102; // código do produto a buscar

function encontrar($array, $chave, $valor){
   foreach($array as $key => $value){
      if($value[$chave] == $valor){
         return $array[$key]['valor'];
      }
   }
}

$resultado = encontrar($valores, 'cod_produto', $buscar);
$cod_produto = $resultado ? $resultado : '0';
echo $cod_produto; // retorna 300
```

**[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/azhhi7)**

Comment: Verdade! O velho `foreach`.. que eu sempre esqueço!

Comment: Rss... mas a sua resposta está ótima!

Comment: Obrigado dvd! =)